# ORA-20547 - can't find info on Oracle error - any references?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Had a PL/SQL application fail today on an Oracle 19 server with an error code of ORA-20547. Unfortunately, the code in question only dumps the ORA- code, it doesn't supply the SQLERRM value. (The evils that developers do live after them...  :-). I've hunted online and haven't found any info on this error. Any info, hints, or references appreciated.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_28547_connection_to_server_failed_probable_oracle_net_admin_error.htm

Comment: ORA-20000+ are for user generated exceptions. Just check the code which raises it.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - I'm just an idiot today. Duh. Thanks for the help. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica btw, it's pretty easy to find using trace events with errorstack: `alter session set events='20547 trace name errorstack level 1, lifetime 10';`

Comment: with this event, you will get PL/SQL error stack in the trace

Comment: More about this: http://orasql.org/2021/05/20/oracle-diagnostic-events-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error numbers from 20000 to 20999 are user-generated errors.

You will not find any documentation for them as you need to check the source code for your application.

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm)

> #### Defining Your Own Error Messages: Procedure `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`
>
> The procedure `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` lets you issue user-defined ORA- error messages from stored subprograms. That way, you can report errors to your application and avoid returning unhandled exceptions.
>
> To call `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`, use the syntax
>
> ```sql
> raise_application_error(
>      error_number, message[, {TRUE | FALSE}]);
> ```
>
> where `error_number` is a negative integer in the range -20000 .. -20999 and message is a character string up to 2048 bytes long. If the optional third parameter is TRUE, the error is placed on the stack of previous errors. If the parameter is `FALSE` (the default), the error replaces all previous errors. `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` is part of package `DBMS_STANDARD`, and as with package `STANDARD`, you do not need to qualify references to it.

Comment: Duh. I knew that. Thanks for the reminder.